# Translation for "Learn more" not used in SO for Teams

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, stack-overflow-for-teams

Translation for ["Learn more"](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=earn%20more%24) (that was completed long time ago) is not used in SO for Teams on ruSO:

> [image: No more to learn]

Other untranslated strings from the image were translated recently and will be on the site in the next builds.

To check the state just open [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) in private mode.

Comment: This isn't supposed to appear but there's a bug so we're investigating and I'll update when I have more information. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Comment: @Catija BTW I found a related [source string with a typo](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15878). It may be used somewhere or just a dead string.

Comment: Looks like we're working on it and will have a fix out in a few days.

Comment: Adam's fixing that string to remove the typo. :)

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the initial announcement, this element wasn't supposed to appear in the left navigation at all on international sites. As such, we've removed this element from the left navigation as of earlier this week (Monday the 22nd of March) so this should no longer be an issue. Thanks for reporting it!

Comment: Still an issue on [rusSE](https://rus.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Did they never go away or did they come back?

Comment: Ah, I see what's going on, it's the Russian language site - sorry... brain being a bit slow today. Could you ask a new question on their meta and I can get it sent to the right team.